# Convert locale long format to short one

Tags: php, locale

I have following locale strings:

```
pl_PL
en_GB
```

Is it possible to convert it with some native function that works with real locale dataset into:

```
pl
en
```

Solutions like:

```
list($short) = explode('_', 'pl_PL');
```

is not expected right now.

Comment: what about php substr function? -> http://it2.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: It's still working on the string directly, not on locale list.

Comment: @Goikiu "That works with real locale dataset ... Solutions like `list($short) = explode(...)` are not expected right now."

Comment: @hsz: `I have following locale strings` -- how are these strings stored, then?

Comment: @AmalMurali I get them from an external application.

Comment: @hsz: But how are they stored? In a text file? Are you fetching it from database? It's not quite clear.

Comment: @AmalMurali Let's say - one locale string in variable. To simplify problem: `$long = 'pl_PL';`

Comment: @hsz: I don't understand what exactly the objection to the `explode` approach is -- what do you want that it doesn't do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`locale_parse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.parselocale.php) from the [`intl` extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) should do this for you. From the documentation:

```
<?php
$arr = locale_parse('sl-Latn-IT-nedis');
if ($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo "$key : $value , ";
        // language : sl , script : Latn , region : IT , variant0 : NEDIS ,
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's a PECL extension and not available by default.

Comment: I didn't realised that it can be available in `intl` - however I think it can be a good solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can using native function [DateFormatter::getLocale](http://php.undmedlibrary.org/manual/ru/dateformatter.getlocale.php)

```
$fmt = new DateFormatter( "pl_PL" ); 
echo $fmt->getLocale();
```

Or without OOP

```
$fmt = datefmt_create( "pl_PL" );
echo datefmt_get_locale($fmt);
```

Output is **pl**

Comment: Somehow `DateFormatter` class is not available, but calling it in @Chris way it works. Thanks !